# Error message: JOIN expression not supported

Tags: ms-access

So I have the following query resulting in the error message mentioned above:

```
SELECT sorg, period, sdst, COUNT(customer_nr) AS total 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(sales_doc), sorg, period FROM orders_baltic LEFT JOIN orders_baltic_sdst ON (sales_doc = salesdoc) WHERE material_name NOT LIKE '*CERT*' AND sdst <> 'HC' AND baltic_orders.period LIKE '2014*') 
GROUP BY sorg, period;
```

I have googled the message, and know the supposed reason (unbracketed JOIN expression comprising string condition). But... there is no string condition in my JOIN expression, and as seen above, I already tried adding brackets. Would be really thankful for any help :)

Comment: If Access is included in your MS Office installation, use the Access query designer to set up your `LEFT JOIN` between *orders_baltic* and *orders_baltic_sdst*.  Start with the simplest possible query: `SELECT *`, no subquery, and no `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`.  After you have a valid join,  build the rest up from there.  Your current query version includes other problems Access hasn't complained about yet.  The query designer can help you avoid those problems.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I was a little bit sloppy in writing up the query. But the error message disappeared after changing the join condition to orders_baltic.sales_doc = orders_baltic_sdst.salesdoc